# I have image upload for CKEDITOR in Django

Tags: django, image, upload, ckeditor

I'm using CKEDITOR for article content in Django. I uploaded image. Image url is image's full path. Example =

```
Image path = /var/www/example/static/image

Image url = /var/www/example/static/image
```

I want to =

Image url = /static/image

How to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The settings variable CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH is an extension of your media directory. So by setting it like this

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
```

you'd end up with an upload path like `<PROJECT_ROOT>/media/uploads/2014/03/29/<FILENAME>`

You can drop the `uploads\` completely and just use an empty string for `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH`